# My coin sprite disappears on various resolutions Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I've been building my shop for my 2D game for a few days now and it is almost finished. Problem is, when I test it for various resolutions, my coin sprite (next to every price text) disappears and I couldn't figure out why.

I tried to change the sprite's max size but didn't work.

Any idea would be very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Edit: Here are some screenshots for 16:9 and 18:9 resolutions.

16:9 - https://ibb.co/dKQNB4K
18:9 - https://ibb.co/ns2KKgr (No coin sprite visible)